# Problems with booting Linux after updating kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-failure

After updating linux headers from 3.5.0-19 into 3.5.0-20 i faced booting problem. I don't know reason, sometimes boots normally, but sometimes i need to reboot 3-4 times. I tried to boot with recovery mode, but i didn't see any error there. 
But with 3.5.0-19 linux boots normally. What's the problem with 3.5.0-20?

Comment: What doesn't work? Why do you have to reboot? Could you clarify your situation?

Comment: Black screen, nothing is working. I need to shutdown my laptop with power key and boot again.

Comment: Got some strange behaviour here too. Login screen freezes and if I switch to virtual console or recovery mode some things don't work either. Nothing specific though, seems a little random. Shutdown doesn't work either. It hangs at writing system time to hardware time or something. I'm guessing same error :-/

Comment: PS: 3.5.0-19 works fine with me too. Problem exists since update to 3.5.0-20.

Comment: Since I and the other guy who had the same problem both have a Lenovo Thinkpad it got me thinking. Do you have a Thinkpad too and if you do, do you have Thinkpad specific software installed? I'm thinking of Fingerprint GUI or thinkfan.

Comment: Problem seems to be solved with kernel 3.5.0-21